# What is the running time when I use system() to call a function?

Tags: time, system, clock

I am trying to calculate the running time of my code. I use the code following.

```
Gettime(start time)
loop
{
   function 1 
   function 2 
   system(compiled excuetable file1 )
   function 4 
   system(compiled excuetable file2 )
   Gettine(time2)
}
```

Then I print out `time2-starttime` to get the time cost each step. I use different time function ( clock, gettimeofday, getusage) to measure them.

There is one question: I know the system called function (compiled executable file1 and compiled executable file2) cost more then all other function in main loop. Because it has its own gettime function inside and it shows it cost more than 1s while the total (time2-starttime) gives me only 0.5 s .

So does that mean (time2-starttime)  I have now do not include the time spend on system()?

Comment: if you are on linux you could just use the time command.

Comment: probably fairly expensive because it creates a process.  You should also avoid using system unless you know EXACTLY what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem, I solved it by `gettimeofday`.
Example:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
int main(){
        struct timeval tvs,tve;
        gettimeofday(&tvs,NULL);
        //system("./test");
        gettimeofday(&tve,NULL);
        double span = tve.tv_sec-tvs.tv_sec + (tve.tv_usec-tvs.tv_usec)/1000000.0;
        printf("time: %.12f\n",span);
        return 0;
}
```